# Generating a list of pages (not posts) without the index file

Tags: html, jekyll

I am using Jekyll as a static generator for a website (not a blog), and I want to have an automatically generated list of all pages on my index page. I get that to work with the following code for the `sidebar.html` file:

```
<ul>
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    <li><div class="drvce"><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></div></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now I would like that the index page is not shown in that list. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used jekyll, but it's main page says that it uses Liquid, and according to [their docs](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/logic), I think the following should work:

```
<ul>
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.title != 'index' %}
    <li><div class="drvce"><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></div></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you a jquery solution

add this in your `<head></head>` tag

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

add this after `</ul>`

```
 <script> $('ul li:first').remove(); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's your main index page that you don't want to show up try this:

```
<ul>
  {% for page in site.pages and page.url != "/" %}
    <li><div class="drvce"><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></div></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```